# Hbase multiple Filters not functioning correctly

Tags: java, hadoop, filter, hbase

I'm using the Java client for HBase.

My `rowkeys` are given in the form `timestamp-userid`.

I have a column named `browser` with values `chrome`, `IE`, etc.

I need to scan through all rows which occurred in the last `7000` minutes where the browser used is Internet Explorer.

I've added 2 filters below. One to check if the `timestamp` (prefix of the `rowkey`) is within a certain range (last `7000` minutes), another to check if the `browser` column value is equal to `IE`.

Here is my code:

```
public static int currentUsersColumn(Table tb, String colname, String colval) throws IOException{

    ArrayList<String> arl = new ArrayList<String>();

    long curtime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    long sevenminsago = curtime - (1000*60*7000);

    FilterList filterList = new FilterList(FilterList.Operator.MUST_PASS_ALL);
    List<MultiRowRangeFilter.RowRange> lst = new ArrayList<MultiRowRangeFilter.RowRange>();
    lst.add(new MultiRowRangeFilter.RowRange(Long.toString(sevenminsago)+"-0", true, Long.toString(curtime)+"-z", true));

    filterList.addFilter(new MultiRowRangeFilter(lst));
    filterList.addFilter(new SingleColumnValueFilter(ColFam, Bytes.toBytes(colname), CompareOp.EQUAL, Bytes.toBytes(colval)));

    Scan s = new Scan();
    s.setFilter(filterList);
    ResultScanner scanner = tb.getScanner(s);

    for(Result rr = scanner.next(); rr!=null; rr = scanner.next()){
            arl.add(Bytes.toString(rr.getRow()));
    }

    return arl.size();

}
```

The problem is even when I put in a random string for `colval` I still get an `ArrayList` of size `400`. Which is clearly incorrect.

I'm guessing my `RowRangeFilter` is incorrect somehow because the `ColumnFilter` seems pretty straight-forward.

Any ideas?

Comment: i just want to say that timestamp in start of rowkey is a performance bottleneck for causing region hotspotting in hbase.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. Any idea what the issue with my code is?

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the values you have coming out? Do they match your query? Without being able to see your data my best guess is you have some rows which don't have the `browser` column, and because you didn't set `setFilterIfMissing(true)` on the `SingleColumnValueFilter` it's including those rows. See [the docs for the filter class](https://hbase.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/filter/SingleColumnValueFilter.html#setFilterIfMissing(boolean)).